# HTML PHP JavaScript Whatever to Check Gmail Unread Count

Tags: php, javascript, html, gmail, safari-extension

How do all these browser plugins, notifiers, etc. check your gmail unread count?

I'm trying to write a Safari Extension (which happens to be in javascript but I don't think it matters) and I can't figure out how to parse the Gmail atom feed (https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom) to get the unread count.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check Google API.

http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/ajax/

Namely http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/ajaxfeeds/

Answer (score 0):

From within a Safari extension, you should be able to do cross-domain [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/xmlhttpreq.html) and use the `responseXML` property to access the DOM.  However, you need to configure the extension to be able to access Google's servers.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041443/safari-5-extension-xmlhttprequest-error-invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11).